# how to not stop video of app PIP mode, when my android app with video is opened in full screen

Tags: android, video, simultaneous

Is there any way to play 2 videos simultaneously (YouTube and my app videoview with mediaplayer)? but when my app video plays, the other Yuotube in PIP mode  stops.

expected - to play my app video on android java. and not stop another app video that is in PIP mode. For example like in "telegram" app